# Build failed: please ensure the remote branch exists (128)

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Not sure if this question goes here or serverfault, but here it goes.

I’m building a couple of automated build rules on [Docker Hub](http://hub.docker.com).
These are my rules:

```
| Branch | master        | /java/tomcat | latest |
| Tag    | /Tomcat(.*)/g | /java/tomcat |        |
```

The first rule builds with no problem, but the second rule fails with the message from the subject:

`Build failed: please ensure the remote branch exists (128)`

It’s like is trying to get a branch named Tomcat which is wrong. Am I doing anything wrong? looks pretty much like a bug to me.

FYI: I have asked this same question in their forum but got no answer.

Comment: Have you tried without `g` or the parentheses?

Comment: yes, and it is mandatory or the trigger button dissapears